# How to determine if two straights are (almost) perpendicular / orthogonal

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv and c++ and have been trying to determine if two lines are  almost perpendicular / orthogonal to each other. There is this formula to determine if they are exactly orthogonal(m1*m2 = -1) whereas m1 is the slope of the first straight and m2 of the second. But lets say if they are 80% orthogonal to each other i want the function to return true. The code so far:

```
bool checkOrtho(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, 
            int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4) 
{ 

int m1, m2; 

// Both lines have infinite slope 
if (x2 - x1 == 0 && x4 - x3 == 0) 
    return false; 

// Only line 1 has infinite slope 
else if (x2 - x1 == 0) { 

    m2 = (y4 - y3) / (x4 - x3); 

    if (m2 == 0) 
        return true; 
    else
        return false; 
} 

// Only line 2 has infinite slope 
else if (x4 - x3 == 0) { 

    m1 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1); 

    if (m1 == 0) 
        return true; 
    else
        return false; 
} 

else { 
    // Find slopes of the lines 
    m1 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1); 
    m2 = (y4 - y3) / (x4 - x3); 

    // Check if their product is -1 
    if (m1 * m2 == -1) 
        return true; 
    else
        return false; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).  For unit vectors, it will give you cos(theta) of the angle between them.  So if they are orthogonal 0, parallel 1.  So you can provide a threshold of how close to orthogonal you wan the lines to be.  Here is the gist:

```
bool checkOrtho(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, 
            int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4,
            float theta_thresh) 
{
    // center around 0
    int h1 = y2 - y1;
    int w1 = x2 - x1;
    int h2 = y4 - y3;
    int w2 = x4 - x3;
    // normalize to unit vectors
    double h1u = h1 / sqrt(pow(h1,2) + pow(w1,2));
    double w1u = w1 / sqrt(pow(h1,2) + pow(w1,2));
    double h2u = h2 / sqrt(pow(h2,2) + pow(w2,2));
    double w2u = w2 / sqrt(pow(h2,2) + pow(w2,2));

    cos_theta = h1u*h2u + w1u*w2u;
    return abs(cos_theta) < theta_thresh;
}
```

Comment: You have two errors: double h1u = h1 / sqrt(h1^2 + w1^2);
        double w1u = w1 / sqrt(h1^2 + w1^2);

Comment: Also, you don't need to normalize if you are going to check strictly with zero.

Comment: True, but the OP wants to have something close to orthogonal, normalizing just makes it more principled

Comment: Yes this worked for me. Keep in mind that if using c++, you don't use "^" for pow. This was pseudo code anyways i guess.

Comment: This is an expensive way to go about determining if two lines are nearly orthogonal. It involves 4 divisions and 4 square roots. If you're using this in a performance needed area, then you should probably try finding a different way to go about doing these calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Two slopes are orthogonal if their degree of intersection is 90 degrees.
Let's say the angle of intersection is 70 degrees. How would you tell if it's 80% orthogonal? Do 70 / 90, which is 0.7777 or 77.77%. So, this angle is not "almost" orthogonal if your criteria is 80%.

You can find an equation to give you the angle of intersection, and there are several answers and approaches to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269050/finding-the-angle-between-two-line-equations/1269620).

I have a working example showing how this works and it's also refactored to help you out. You can use the functions with how your code is now without any issue.
Perks of using floating type numbers is that they have built in infinities. Using the function `std::isinf()` will tell you if a value is infinity and is set if you try dividing a floating type by 0. This also helps simplify your code.

I have a live running code sample here: https://godbolt.org/z/AKauq5

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

using Point = std::pair<int , int>; //x , y



/**
 * Takes two slopes and returns the angle in radians.
 * Does not work for lines parallel to the y access.
 */
double angleFromSlope(double m1, double m2)
{
  double numerator = m1 - m2;
  double denominator = 1 + m1*m2;
  return std::atan( std::abs(numerator/denominator));  
}

/**
 * Get the slope of a line.
 */
double slopeOfLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    // Point.second is y
    // Point.first is x
    return (p2.second - p1.second) / ( p2.first - p1.first);
}

/**
 * Converts radians to degrees.
 */
double radToDeg(double theta)
{
    constexpr double PI = 4*std::atan(1); // constexpr just means to evaluate at compile time
    return theta * (180.0d / PI);
}

/**
 * Uses a threshold to tell user if line is "kind of" orthogonal.
 * Works by calculating angle between lines, then finding the percentage;
 */
bool isKindOfOrthogonal(double m1, double m2)
{
    // two lines are orthogonal if their angles are 90* 
    const double orthoTheta = 90.0f;

    // must be 0.80 or above to be considered orthogonal
    const double orthoThreshold = 0.80d;

    // lets get the angle 
    double theta = angleFromSlope(m1, m2);

    // now convert to degrees
    theta = radToDeg(theta);

    // calculate how similar they are
    double similarity = theta / orthoTheta;
    return similarity >= orthoThreshold;
}

void printOrthogonal(double m1, double m2)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha // this just says to print true and false
              << "Are slopes " << m1 << " and " << m2 << " kind of orthogonal?: "
              << isKindOfOrthogonal(m1, m2) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    // two numbers that aren't orthogonal
    double m1_1 = 4;
    double m1_2 = 1;

    // two numbers that are orthogonal
    double m2_1 = 4.0d;
    double m2_2 = -0.25d;

    // two numbers that are kind of orthogonal
    double m3_1 = 4.0d;
    double m3_2 = -0.05d;

    // Give two points, calculate the slope
    Point p1 {1, 2};
    Point p2 {3, 4};
    double m4 = slopeOfLine(p1, p2);
    std::cout << "Slope of line from p1 and p2: " << m4 << "\n";

    // run these tests
    printOrthogonal(m1_1, m1_2);
    printOrthogonal(m2_1, m2_2);
    printOrthogonal(m3_1, m3_2);

    return 0;
}
```